# Why is this resulting in a unexpected T_ECHO error?

Tags: php, syntax-error

First time I've encountered this T_ECHO error..

```
  function cart($items, $args) {
    $items .= '<li id="menu-item-cart" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-cart">' . echo do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]'); . '</li>';
        return $items;
}
```

How can I make this work so my shortcode is displayed within that li?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'...' . echo do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]'); . '...'
```

should be

```
'...' . do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]') . '...'
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, no error now. Although the shortcode now doesn't display in the menu and using firebug, that whole <li> is greyed out?

Comment: Ok finally got it. It works great! Thank you GWW! The only thing it doesn't do is keep the cart message within the <li>. It hangs around outside of the body.. can I force it to stay within that li? I'm using the cart66lite plugin > shortcode manager.

Comment: @iCeR: If it's surrounded by the `<li>` it should remain in it unless the `do_shortcode` function is doing something funky.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put an additional `echo` in the middle of string concatenation.

```
function cart($items, $args) {
    $items .= '<li id="menu-item-cart" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-cart">' . do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]') . '</li>';
        return $items;
}
```

Comment: Cheers guys, just now that <li> is greyed out (debugging uding firebug as that li is not being displayed)

Comment: Seems that it's due to the <li> contents being empty, yet if I use that shortcode anywhere else, outside of that function, it works?

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$items .= '<li id="menu-item-cart" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-cart">' . do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]') . '</li>';
return $items;
```

and `echo` your function,

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this :

```
    function cart($items, $args) {
            $items .= '<li id="menu-item-cart" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-cart">'.do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]').'</li>';
            return $items;
    }
```